# Windows: What are the security implication of adding Network Service account to "Event Log Readers" group?

Tags: windows, security, event-log

I want to read security audit logs from a network service. By default, Network Service does not have permission to read but it can if the account is added to "Event Log Readers". One of the examples is mentioned [here](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH98010.html).

However, I want to understand what would be security implications of this. Does it pose a considerable security threat?

Answer (score 1):

The security implications really go by which machine and what it's running.  For instance, if you have a development machine that dumps verbose errors which include login information as the developers troubleshoot, that data becomes visible to anything running as Network Service, in your scenario.  You'd never want to do this in an SQL environment, as you may compromise security by dumping connection string information or specifics on failed login events to say the very least. A dumb internet terminal without intranet access, however, is likely to be safer, as you wouldn't put critical data on that or allow it to log into anything behind your firewall.

Instead, Windows has a feature called [Event Forwarding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/use-windows-event-forwarding-to-assist-in-intrusion-detection) that is designed to forward the events to a server using a similar approach, but a secured, specific login instead of just Network Service's generic login.  Even without forwarding, it's better to use a secured login that isn't common to other networks instead of the generic login for network services that comes with Windows.